# multiple search conditions in one query in es and distinguish the items according to the conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

For one case I need to put multiple search conditions in one query to reduce the number of queries we need.

However, I need to distinguish the returning items based on the conditions.

Currently I achieved this goal by using function score query, specifically: each condition is assigned with a score, and I can differentiate the results based on those scores.

However, the performance is not that good. Plus now we need to get the doc count of each condition.

So is there any way to do it? I'm thinking using aggregation, but not sure if I can do it.

Thanks!

update:

```
curl -X GET 'localhost:9200/locations/_search?fields=_id&from=0&size=1000&pretty' -d '{
"query":{
  "bool":{
    "should":[
      {
        "filtered":{
          "filter":{
            "bool":{
              "must":[{"term":{"city":"new york"}},{"term":{"state":"ny"}}]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "filtered":{
          "filter":{
            "bool":{
              "must":[{"term":{"city":"los angeles"}},{"term":{"state":"ca"}}]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to answer the first part of your question , names queries are the best.
For eg:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field1": {
              "query": "qbox",
              "_name": "firstQuery"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "field2": {
              "query": "hosted Elasticsearch",
              "_name": "secondQuery"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will return an additional field called matched_queries for each hit which will have the information on queries matched for that document.
You can find more info on names queries [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-named-queries-and-filters.html)

But this this information cant be used for aggregation.
So you need to handle the second part of your question in a separate manner. 
Filter aggregation for each query type would be the idea solution here.
For eg:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text": {
              "query": "qbox",
              "_name": "firstQuery"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "source": {
              "query": "elasticsearch",
              "_name": "secondQuery"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "firstQuery": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "text": "qbox"
        }
      }
    },
    "secondQuery": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "source": "elasticsearch"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more on filter aggregation [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation)

Comment: Currently I have a bool-must query in the top should query. Not sure where to put the _name tag. Any hint?

Comment: Put it inside the query like i have put "             "_name":"firstQuery""

Comment: I posted the query that I use. I insert the _name into the filter body but it does not work.

Comment: Can you put it inside bool

Comment: actually can we set the return size for each named query condition?